# XPath to select element based on sibling/cousin text?

Tags: html, xml, xpath, scrapy

I am attempting to scrape the contact details for the `Chief Executive` and `Someone Else`

I can find the Chief Executive using the the following code

```
response.xpath('*/div[@class="outer"]/h2/text()="Chief Executive"')

# Returns a Selector
[<Selector xpath='*/div[@class="outer"]/h2/text()="Chief Executive"' data=u'0'>]
```

But as soon as I attempt to access parents or siblings I either get errors or no data.

Here are some patterns that I have tried

1.

```
response.xpath('*/div[@class="outer"]/h2/text()="Chief Executive"/following-sibling')

ValueError: XPath error: Invalid type in */div[@class="outer"]/h2/text()="Chief Executive"/following-sibling
```

2.

```
response.xpath('*/div[@class="outer"]/h2/text()="Chief Executive"/following-sibling::content')

ValueError: XPath error: Invalid type in */div[@class="outer"]/h2/text()="Chief Executive"/following-sibling::content
```

3.

```
response.xpath('*/div[@class="outer"]/h2/text()="Chief Executive"/parent::*')

ValueError: XPath error: Invalid type in */div[@class="outer"]/h2/text()="Chief Executive"/parent::*
```

4

```
response.xpath('*/div[@class="outer"]/h2/text()="Chief Executive"/..')

ValueError: XPath error: Invalid type in */div[@class="outer"]/h2/text()="Chief Executive"/..
```

5

```
response.xpath('*/div[@class="outer"]/h2[.="Chief Executive"]')

[] # No data found
```

6

```
response.xpath('*/div[@class="outer"]/h2[text()="Chief Executive"]')

[] # No data found
```

Base HTML

```
<div class="outer">
    <h2 class="legend">
    Chief Executive
    </h2>

    <div class="fieldset">

    <div class="display-row">
        <div class="display-label">Contact name:</div>
        <div class="display-field-no-width">
        Mr. Steven Bob
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="display-row">
        <div class="display-label">Job title:</div>
        <div class="display-field-no-width">
        Chief Executive Officer
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="display-row">
        <div class="display-label">Organisation name:</div>
        <div class="display-field-no-width">
        1 COMAPNY PTY LTD
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
</div>


<div class="outer">
    <h2 class="legend">
    Someone Else
    </h2>

    <div class="fieldset">

    <div class="display-row">
        <div class="display-label">Contact name:</div>
        <div class="display-field-no-width">
        Mr. Steven Bob
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="display-row">
        <div class="display-label">Job title:</div>
        <div class="display-field-no-width">
        Chief Executive Officer
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="display-row">
        <div class="display-label">Organisation name:</div>
        <div class="display-field-no-width">
        1 COMAPNY PTY LTD
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This XPath,

```
normalize-space(//div[normalize-space(h2)='Chief Executive']
                /div[div[1]='Contact name:'])
```

will return

```
Mr. Steven Bob
```

Following this pattern, you can select other fields from this entry or from the entry for `Someone Else`, as requested.

Comment: Thanks kjhughes, ultimately real problem was that the data I was after was being loaded in afterwards via AJAX and I did not notice this from my server side scraping, but once I got that sorted, the normalize-space also gave me the write search